# Problemas con el SELECT2 no trae algunos datos (bootstrap)

Tags: bootstrap, select, select2, buscador

Estoy haciendo una consulta y me presenta peculiaridad, a ver si a alguien le sucedió.

Quiero usar el **`select2`**, de la manera mas simple le pongo al `select` la clase y en `js` pongo:

```
$('.select2').select2();
```

El `select` lo relleno con un `select * from` comun de `sql server,` cuando ejecuto el `select` me trae todos los valores, pero cuando lo paso al `select` de mi pagina no trae varios.

Por otro lado a veces se tilda y muestra este:

> "Searching..."

Si a alguno le pasó agradecería mucho que me comenten como lo solucionaron así no tengo que recurrir a un buscador distinto.

Gracias!!!!

[image: select2]
CODIGO: Estoy haciendo una web sencilla con php puro por eso hago la consulta directamente así

```
$sql_locomotora = "select id,numero from MaterialRodante where IdTipoMaterialRodante=1 and EstaOperativo=1 and Numero not like '%movil%' order by Numero";
$stmt_locomotora = sqlsrv_query( $con_material, $sql_locomotora);       
if( $stmt_locomotora === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
while($locomotora = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_locomotora)){
    $locomotoras[]= '<option value="0" selected disabled></option><option id="'.$locomotora['id'].'" value="'.$locomotora['id'].'" >'.$locomotora['numero'].'</option>';
}
```

Y luego hago un print en el select que le pongo la clase (empiezo a sospechar que puede haber problema por hacerlo así)

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Locomotora</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 80px;" id="locomotora" name="locomotora">
                <?php
                print_r($locomotoras);
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

NOTA: Si le saco la clase select2 funciona y me trae todos los valores.

Perdón la desprolijidad es mi primer pregunta.

Comment: Hola, puedes subir el código de como llenas el `select` con la consulta, puede que estes mostrando mal los datos

Comment: Gracias, es posible ahi lo edito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas insertando la primera opcion dentro del bucle.  Debes de sacar la opcion con `value=0` afuera del `while` asi:

```
$sql_locomotora = "select id,numero from MaterialRodante where IdTipoMaterialRodante=1 and EstaOperativo=1 and Numero not like '%movil%' order by Numero";
$stmt_locomotora = sqlsrv_query( $con_material, $sql_locomotora);       
if( $stmt_locomotora === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
$locomotoras[]= '<option value="0" selected disabled></option>';
while($locomotora = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_locomotora)){
    $locomotoras[]= '<option id="'.$locomotora['id'].'" value="'.$locomotora['id'].'" >'.$locomotora['numero'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, gracias a eso me muestra todos los datos!! muchas gracias por la respuesta!